# Is there a way to change a project from using API 12 to API 8

Tags: android

I set up my project to use Android 3.2 (API Level 12), but it seems like a lot of phones are still using Android 2.2 (API Level 8).

Is there a way to change my project from only supporting Android 3.2+ to supporting back to Android 2.2?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right Click Project -> Properties -> Android -> Select SDK version
2. Update Manifest, min/target api. (as others have described by others).

Answer (score 2):

yes...just change the minsdk number in the manifest. You have to be sure that you don't use any feature that is not supported though...

Answer (score 2):

in your `AndroidManifest.xml` add this line:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

`android:minSdkVersion` tells the Store what the minimum version you are targeting is.  In this case 2.2.  Devices less than 2.2 won't be able to download your app.

`android:targetSdkVersion` tells the store what the best version you are developing for is.  In this case 4.1.  Devices over 4.1 can still download your app but certain features may run in compatibility mode.

NOTE:  When you setup your project to use 3.2, all you did was select the Android SDK you wanted your IDE to use when checking and compiling your code. Without the `uses-sdk` line in your manifest you've targeted nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Manifest.xml file and edit the minSdkVersion to 4. That will set it way back to 1.5 or something like that :). You can make that number higher if you want to suit a higher API, but I like compatibility.